# Java different type objects as same parameter

Tags: java

I am currently writing an function for manipulate several ArrayList.

All the elements have same constructor, how can I do it like below?

```
Class A{
public A (Cursor data){...}
}

Class B{
public B (Cursor data){...}
}

Class C{
public C (Cursor data){...}
}

public void dataManipulation(ArrayList<**?**> list, Cursor cursor){
cursor.moveToFirst();
for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
            list(new **?**(cursor));
            if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
                cursor.moveToNext();

}

public void main(){
ArrayList<A> listA = new ArrayList<A>();
ArrayList<B> listB = new ArrayList<B>();
ArrayList<C> listC = new ArrayList<C>();

Cursor cursor = IMPORT_CURSOR_FROM_FILE;

dataManipulation(listA, cursor);
dataManipulation(listB, cursor);
dataManipulation(listC, cursor);
}
```

Comment: Create a common interface for `A`, `B` and `C` to implement which guarantees compatibility for the functionality that you require

Comment: Thanks for reply, could you show some sample code? As I am a newbie of programming

Comment: You don't call your example right.  I'm not sure where you're getting your cursor from that `main` method (which isn't the same as `public static void main(String[] args)`, mind you).  Also, what is `list(new **?**(cursor))` meant to represent?

Comment: My fault, I just forgot cursor is needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Interfaces and Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html), basically an interface is a contract that gurentees that any object that implements that interface will provide the contractual functionality...

For example...

```
public interface CursorContainer {
    public Cursor getCursor();
}
```

You "common" class would implement this interface and provide implementations for the `getCursor` (and any other required) method...

```
Class A implements CursorContainer {
    public A (Cursor data){...}
}

Class B implements CursorContainer  {
    public B (Cursor data){...}
}

Class C implements CursorContainer  {
    public C (Cursor data){...}
}
```

Then you could use generics...

```
public void dataManipulation(ArrayList<CursorContainer> list, Cursor cursor){
```

Your next problem is know how to create a particular implementation, for this, you will need a factory...

```
public interface CursorContainerFactory {
    public CursorContainer create(Cursor cursor);
}
```

You would need a factory for each type of container you want to create...

```
public Class CursorContainerAFactory implements CursorContainerFactory {
    public CursorContainer create(Cursor cursor) {
        return new A(cursor);
    }
}
```

You would then need to supply the factory to your `dataManipulation` method...

```
public void dataManipulation(ArrayList<CursorContainer> list, CursorContainerFactory factory, Cursor cursor){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        list(factory.create(cursor));
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
            cursor.moveToNext();

}
```

And finally, call it...

```
dataManipulation(listA, new CursorContainerAFactory(), cursor);
```

Remember, classes can implement many interfaces, but only extend from one...

Comment: Is there any reason that it couldn't be `List<? extends CursorContainer>`?

Comment: If that's the case, then it could be shifted to `List<? super CursorContainer>`.  I didn't see anywhere that we were writing to the list at first (I *guess* that's what `list(new **?**(cursor));` means), but I also don't see anywhere that we read from the list, either.

Comment: Just to spoil your fun even further, `implements` has an `s` on the end.

Comment: @ajb I also implemented `CursorContainer` on the factory implementation, but at least I caught that one :P

Comment: @Makoto Sure, but what's the benefit (of `<? super CursorContainer>` over `<CursorContainer>`)? I'm assuming the OP wants to read it later...

Comment: It makes it explicit as to what that collection's purpose is.  Are you reading from it, are you writing to it, or doing both?  Also enforces compile-time safety of it as well.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create an interface for each of your classes (A, B, C) to implement.

See this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Comment: Hmm, and what about `list(new **?**(cursor));`?

Comment: You could just substitute cursor for A,B, or C

Comment: But how do you know which one is to be used?

Comment: I don't, since I have no clue what the program is being used for. I would imagine you could use a switch statement for this, however.

Answer (score 1):

You might use reflection, but you'll need to pass in the `Class` because of type-erasure. Something like,

```
public <T> void dataManipulation(Class<T> cls, ArrayList<T> list,
        Cursor cursor) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        Constructor<T>[] ctors = (Constructor<T>[]) cls.getConstructors();
        for (Constructor<T> c : ctors) {
            Type[] types = c.getGenericParameterTypes();
            if (types.length == 1) {
                if (types[0].getClass().equals(Cursor.class)) {
                    list.add(c.newInstance(cursor));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}
```